# Azure Function: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage assembly not found

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-functions

```
    [15/03/2018 11:03:14 PM] Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=8.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Could not find or load a specific file. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131621)
[15/03/2018 11:03:14 PM]    at Tux.Workers.RollCall.Azure.AzureTable.<Init>d__1.MoveNext()
[15/03/2018 11:03:14 PM]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
[15/03/2018 11:03:14 PM]    at Tux.Workers.RollCall.Azure.AzureTable.Init(String tableName)
[15/03/2018 11:03:14 PM]    at Tux.Workers.RollCall.Function1.<Run>d__0.MoveNext()
[15/03/2018 11:03:14 PM] Function completed (Success, Id=438dae86-18a8-4c85-b121-3918e2307ca4, Duration=122ms)
[15/03/2018 11:03:14 PM] Executed 'Function1' (Succeeded, Id=438dae86-18a8-4c85-b121-3918e2307ca4)
```

No matter how I do this error always occur whenever trying to calling Cloud Service in Azure function project. I can see the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll file in the bin directory inside the project. I also see the dll inside

```
C:\Users\klam0\.nuget\packages\windowsazure.storage\8.6.0
```

When I create a basic console application, I have no problem calling the Cloud to get the table reference.

Do I need to configure something on the portal if I just run the project locally?